# How to handle data race using select() in C++ on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, select, mutex

I am working with several network-sockets and handle them with callbacks from a select()-loop (Windows 7, 64-bit)

I now want to protect the variables accessed by the callbacks now from data corruption produced by data races. Is it possible to solve that with mutexes? I ask, since I am not using threads, but callbacks from the select loop and getting a std::system_error at the moment, when lock() is called the second time.

Second question: Would it be better to use threads instead of a select()-loop with regard to compatibility to other systems (*nix)?

Thanks!

Comment: What data races? If all the callbacks are called by the select-ing thread?

Comment: The callbacks can access shared objects. So two callbacks - that would be enough - could add data to the shared object at the same time. That could happen if a started callback needs some time before it accesses the shared object and meanwhile another callback was started with immediate data access.

Comment: If you're using `select()` then - from the perspective of your code - it's all single threaded and you don't need and mutexes.  Both threads and mutexes are portable to all modern UNIX systems - no reason to prefer either for portability.

Comment: Thanks Tony D! So is it correct, that select() is blocking my application, then starting a callback and blocking again? So there would be no option to work something in the application in the background? Working beside select() would need threads?!

Comment: They can't add things add the same time if they're both called from the same thread, can they?